# PHPExcel Formatting Problems

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel

I'm trying to make all rows below the main titles, starting with row three, formatted with alternating colors (white/grey). THe formatting for the titles is fine, but when I apply this code,

```
$lastRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
   for ($row = 3; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
      if ($row % 2 == 0) {
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($row)->applyFromArray(
            array(
               'fill' => array(
                 'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                 'color' => array('rgb' => 'CCD6DE')
               )
            )
         );
      }
   }
```

I get issues with the data. Here are the images: [Without](http://imgur.com/SbV2DeF) this code, [With](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdx0H.jpg) this code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Row and Column styles aren't implemented in PHPExcel, you need to apply your style to a range of cells:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A' . $row . ':E' . $row)
    ->applyFromArray(
        array(
            'fill' => array(
                'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => array('rgb' => 'CCD6DE')
            )
        )
    );
```